Unable to switch Node.js versions using nvm in Bitbucket pipeline on Windows runner
I have installed nvm on my Windows runner and successfully installed two Node.js versions: 16.15.0 and 6.9.1. When I try to switch between these versions manually using the command nvm use {version} on the runner, it works as expected.
However, when I try to switch between Node.js versions using the same nvm use {version} command in the Bitbucket pipeline YAML file, it doesn't work. The pipeline doesn't switch the Node.js version as intended.
Here are the details:
Operating System: Windows
nvm-windows is installed, and I can switch Node.js versions manually.
The pipeline fails to switch the version programmatically using nvm use {version} in the script.
How can I achieve this Node.js version switch within the Bitbucket pipeline?
Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated!
I have tried two switch the node version using nvm through bitbucket pipeline . But my version is not getting switched .Please help

How have you written the command in the pipeline?
